# vim regex to match inline comments

Tags: regex, vim, comments

Assuming the following sample inline comment:

```
/*
function newMethodName (int bar, String s) {
   int i = 123;
}
s/\<foo\s*(/newMethodName (/g
*/
```

How would I match and replace such that it would, essentially, become uncommented. I got this far before giving up.

```
:%s/\/\*\(\_.\)*\*\//\1/
```

Solution

```
:%s/\/\*\(\_.*\)\*\//\1/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your capture group ( ) is capturing one character or newline. Put the following * inside so that \1 replacement gets the whole string rather than just the first character.

Comment: As a point of clarification for others, because it took me a bit to understand your answer, the * needs to be moved inside the capture group.  So the command becomes `:%s/\/\*\(\_.*\)\*\//\1/`.  Interestingly `:%s/\/\*\(\_.\+\)*\*\//\1/` also works (at least for the example).  Perhaps someone who's not as tired as I am can explain why (because I haven't a clue).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. [Sometimes I read/post on my phone in my idle time and typing punctuation is less than convenient.] So `\(\_.\)*` creates as many capture groups `\1` `\2` etc as it matches, `\(\_.*\)` creates one capture group `\1` which matches the run of zero or more characters.

Comment: Thanks karmakaze! karategeek6, using \+ instead ended up hanging vim (on a win box); seems that should have worked but for some reason didn't. I'll have to try it on a 'nix box later.